# Can't open simple Console Application with Visual Studio 2015 CTP Preview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-2015, ctp

I downloaded Visual Studio 2015 CTP Preview because I wanted to test to see if I could load in a Roslyn Code Issue extension.

When I try to create a simple console application using **New Project -> Console Aplication** I am getting the following error dialog.

[image]

Any ideas what might be causing this? I have reinstalled and same issue.

Comment: Try to create a new console app ( without that extension ). Close your VS, and re-open the application that you just created. If that works, that means your installation is correct. If it does't then re-install your VS and try again.

Comment: Yeah, when I do that, it will open the solution (which it wouldn't do before), but the solution is empty, and when I go to add a console project again, it gives the same error. Let me try to reinstall and see if I screwed something up.

Comment: Try deleting `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

Comment: Is this in the experimental instance? I had a similar problem and deleted my entire `%appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0{ExperimentalName}\ `folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found the solution on another site. Here are the steps that need to be performed:

```
Open a Visual Studio command window with admin privileges. This can be done from Windows search after clicking on the Windows button (or Start button - depending on the OS) located in the lower left corner. Make sure that you don't have any Visual Studio project open before proceeding.

Type in prompt in the search box and select "Developer Command Prompt". Right click on this and select run with admin privileges.

In the command window Enter:
```

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

```
In the command window then enter:
```

devenv /installvstemplates